# rancher sidekick php-fpm ports mapping

Tags: php, docker, nginx, rancher, fpm

I'm using rancher with this docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  data: {}
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
    - /some_local_dir/services.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    volumes_from:
    - my-service
    ports:
    - 9082:80
    labels:
      io.rancher.sidekicks: my-service
  my-service:
    image: my-service
    volumes:
    - my-service:/my-service
    ports:
    - 9001:9000
```

my-service - is image build upon alpine3.6, with installed  php7-fpm

My services.conf is:

```
server {
    root /my-service/web;
    server_name my-service.local;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass my-service.web:9001;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

        # increase url max size passed to fast CGI interface
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;

        internal;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/my-service_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-service_access.log;
}
```

And then I'm getting error :

> [error] 10#10: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.42.0.1, upstream: "fastcgi://10.42.94.81:9001"

When I remove port mapping, and left fpm port uncahnged  (9000:9000)
All starts working

[Github helped me](https://github.com/matriphe/docker-alpine-nginx/issues/1)  to find the reason why php-fpm7 wasn't working in the first place, I've updated /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf in my-service image, instead of default

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

I wrote

```
listen = 9000
```

It makes things works for 9000:9000, but for 9001:9000 - nope ((

Please help to understand how can I forward fpm to 9001, in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I misused configs, following entry for the ranchers **sidekick** means that my-service:9001 will be open for the all **external** containers, while 9000 remains for the parent container.

```
my-service:
    image: my-service
    volumes:
    - my-service:/my-service
    ports:
    - 9001:9000
```

So I don't need port mapping at all , if I don't want to expose fpm to external containers.

If there is a need to work on 9001, only way is to redefine defaults of fpm and start it on 9001, or even a more right way - is to use separate pool for the application.